# Using SinonJS stub (with rewire)

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon, stub

I have a function:

```
var publish = function(a, b, c) {
    main = a + getWriterName(b,c);
}
```

and getWriterName is another function:

```
var getWriterName = function(b,c) {
    return 'Hello World';
}
```

I want to test the "publish" function but I do not want to run the "getWriterName" function while I am testing "publish". I feel like I stub getWriterName function because I don't want to run it everytime I test "publish", but how do I do that? I did something like:

```
var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
sandbox.stub(getWriterName).returns('done');
```

But this gives me an error of

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function

What is wrong with my stubbing if I am in the write path?

Edit:
I am using rewire so would like solutions using rewire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

If my functions are in a file called `main.js` then firstly I'd rewire the file as:

```
var main = rewire('main');
```

Then to stub any other function being called in one function, in my case, when I had to stub `getWriterName` I'd do:

```
main.__set__('getWriterName', function(b, c) {
    return 'Something Else'
}
```

and Finally after finishing using it, do

```
main.restore();
```

Comment: The first part worked, but when I tried to restore I got "[myrewiredfile].restore is not a function"

Comment: From https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire:
__ set __ returns a function which reverts the changes introduced by this particular __ set __ call

var revert = myModule.__set__("port", 3000);
 
// port is now 3000
revert();
// port is now the previous value

Answer (score 9):

This is how Sinon can be used with Rewire to stub a function. Rewire in this case is particularly useful if the stubbed function is private.

```
it('getWriteName always returns "Hello World"', function() {      
    var stub = sandbox.stub();
    stub.returns('Hello World');
    var unset = log.__set__('getWriterName', stub);

    // your test and expectations here

    unset();
    // it's always good to restore the previous state
});
```

Comment: what is log variable in above statement log.__set__ ?

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne I believe `log` would be the name of the imported object, i.e. `const log = rewire('/path/to/module')`, though I have no idea why that name was chosen.

Answer (score 0):

From sinon docs: "The `sinon.sandbox.create(config)` method is mostly an integration feature, and as an end-user of Sinon.JS you will probably not need it."

Normally you create a sinon stub with the syntax:

```
sinon.stub(obj, 'property, function(){
      //do something
}
```

Let's say that somewhere in your file you are exporting these two functions

```
//somefile.js
var publish = function(a, b, c) {
    main = a + getWriterName(b,c);
}

var getWriterName = function(b,c) {
    return 'Hello World';
}
exports.getWriterName = getWriterName;
exports.publish  = publish;
```

Importing them in your tests:

```
var someFile = require('./somefile.js');
```

And trying to stub out the method you'd like to:

```
sinon.stub(someFile, 'getWriterName', function(b, c) {
    return 'done'
});
```

You'll find that this too won't work. This is because sinon can't actually stub out a method that has been required unless it can access it as a property of the file you required. In order for this to work, you'd need to be doing this:

//somefile.js

```
var getWriterName = function(b,c) {
    return 'Hello World';
}
exports.getWriterName = getWriterName;

var publish = function(a, b, c) {
    main = a + exports.getWriterName(b,c);
}
exports.publish  = publish;
```

Now the getWriterName is accessible for stubbing out once you import the file with the functions into your tests. You'd do it just like the above example:

```
sinon.stub(someFile, 'getWriterName', function(b, c) {
    return 'done'
});
```

And can undo it with:

```
someFile.getWriterName.restore();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted a solution using rewire rather than require

Comment: How would this work if the function we wanted to stub was part of a default export?

Comment: I feel like I'm going crazy because I can't find any difference in the to codes you wrote except the order of the statements. What is the difference between the version that works and the version that doesn't work?